# Wait\Depend on resources in parent from module

Tags: azure, reference, virtual-machine, terraform

I create the resource group and the vNet in the `main.tf` and I reference module in the same file. The problem is, module cannot access these resources from the module. related code (most of the code removed, only relevant parts left):

`main.tf`:

```tf
module "worker" {
  source = "./vmLoop"

  vmName = "worker"
  prefix = "${var.reference["name"]}"
  loop   = "${var.reference["workerCount"]}"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "${var.reference["name"]}"
  location = "${var.reference["location"]}"
}
```

How do I reference this resource group in the module? inside `main.tf` I can do this: `"${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"`. Not only that, if I want to use data inside the module, that would fail because the resource is not yet created (most of the code removed, only relevant parts left):

`Module.tf`:

```tf
data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = "${var.prefix}"
}
```

Everything works fine if I precreate resource group\vnet.

In arm template, I would add a `dependsOn` property. However, modules in terraform do not support `depends_on`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a fairly *hackish* workaround to this.

You can use depends_on on output variables of upstream module in the downstream, **BUT** you must make sure you use the variable in the downstream module, not just use it in the depends_on clause.

Unfortunately, that's not an ideal solution and it might not be applicable in some situations.

Comment: hey, can you provide some example code, i dont really understand this explanation, sorry

Comment: A code snippet will be WAY TOO LONG, so I will explain here. The idea is that, when you are calling a module you are most probably going to have output variables. You can use those values in other modules. So, what you can do is, use the **depends_on = output_var** clause when calling the second moudle. But you must make sure, that somewhere inside that second module, you use the output variable you have passed to your depends_on clause. I am not profficient in Azure, but in AWS, e.g. Create VPC > Pass ID as depends_on value > Use VPC_ID in the second module.

Comment: in my case i dont have output value and I dont have a module thats preceding this module, only main.tf that calls the module. as you clearly know what you are talking about - you got a link to aws example?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't , I used this approach on a project I worked for, but we can start a chat so we don't spam here and discuss better.

Comment: Bah, an option here in the comments should show, where you start it ...., thought it was already there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184018/discussion-between-alexk-and-4c74356b41).

Answer (score 1):

In the module you should be passing the subnetID or resource group, or whatever you are creating as a variable.  For instance in your main config you might call the following:

```
module "vnet" {
  source              = "Azure/network/azurerm"
  resource_group_name = "${var.resource_group}"
  vnet_name           = "${terraform.workspace}-vnet"
  location            = "${var.arm_region}"
  address_space       = "${var.arm_network_address_space}"
  subnet_prefixes     = ["${var.arm_subnet1_address_space}", "${var.arm_subnet2_address_space}"]
  subnet_names        = ["subnet1", "subnet2"]

  tags = {
    environment = "${terraform.workspace}"
  }
}
```

Then invoke your vmdeploy module that using the subnetID as follows:

```
module "vmdeploy" {
 source = "./vmdeploy"
 subnetID = "${module.vnet.vnet_subnets[0]}"
}
```

By referencing the other module as a value for the vmdeploy module you are creating an implicit dependency that Terraform will recognize and include in the resource graph.

Within the module itself you would define a variable called subnetID like this:

```
var "subnetID" {}
```

Does that help?

Comment: hey Ned, thanks (and thanks for your course on tf)! this is more or less what I'm doing right now as a wordaround. I was hoping for a less hackish way

Comment: I wouldn't mix variable cases. Just stick with snake case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the name of the Resource Group to the module. 
i.e.:

```
module "worker" {
  source = "./vmLoop"

  rg     = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"    
  vmName = "worker"
  prefix = "${var.reference["name"]}"
  loop   = "${var.reference["workerCount"]}"
}
```

Then in the worker module code itself, you would use the `rg` var for the worker's Resource Group.

Comment: yeah, but like I said, the problem is the subnet resource, rg resource is just to showcase.